# Can I import my Chrome bookmarks into Firefox?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-extensions, firefox-extensions

I just switched from Chrome to Firefox and I was wondering if I can get my bookmarks out of Chrome and into Firefox somehow. Is it possible to export to some standard format and import into Firefox?

Thanks

Comment: Are you by chance running Chrome or Firefox on Ubuntu? Additionally, the "suggested" duplicate accepted answer appears to be a bit outdated so you may find that that is not 100% accurate now 4 years later.

Answer (score 2):

### How to Export Bookmarks from Chrome and Import into Firefox

**1. Export from Chrome**

Firstly, open **Chrome** and press <kbd>**Ctrl**</kbd>+<kbd>**Shift**</kbd>+<kbd>**O**</kbd> to open the **Bookmark Manager**. Now click the dropdown arrow beside **Organize**, select **Export bookmarks to HTML file...**, and now save the file somewhere you can find and access for the **Import into Firefox** step.

[image]

**2. Import into Firefox**

Secondly, open **Firefox** and press <kbd>**Ctrl**</kbd>+<kbd>**Shift**</kbd>+<kbd>**B**</kbd> to open the Library window. Now click the dropdown arrow beside **Import and Backup**, select the **Import Bookmarks from HTML...**, and now select the HTML file you saved in the first step by **double-clicking it** or highlighting it and selecting **Open**.

[image]